# nested boost::shared_ptr use_count not updating

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

I have a nested boost::shared_ptr which was occasionally getting destroyed when getting assigned to another one and going out of scope. I figured out that the use_count was not updating unless I copy the pointer to a temp. The code is self-explanatory. In the first for-loop, the use_count doesn't update, whereas it updates on the other.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  typedef int T;
  typedef std::vector<T> content_1d_t;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<content_1d_t> storage_1d_t;
  typedef std::vector<storage_1d_t> content_2d_t;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<content_2d_t> storage_2d_t;

  int dim1 = 10;
  int dim2 = 1;
  content_2d_t* content_1 = new content_2d_t();
  content_1->reserve(dim2);
  storage_2d_t storage_1(content_1);

  for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
  {
    storage_1->push_back(storage_1d_t(new content_1d_t(dim1)));
  }

  //content_2d_t* content_2 = new content_2d_t(dim2);
  storage_2d_t storage_2 = storage_1;

  for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
  {
    cout<< "use count before : "<< storage_1->operator[](i).use_count()<<endl;
    storage_2->operator[](i) = storage_1->operator[](i);
    cout<< "use count after: "<< storage_1->operator[](i).use_count()<<endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i)
  {
    cout<< "use count before : "<< storage_1->operator[](i).use_count()<<endl;
    storage_1d_t ref = storage_1->operator[](i);
    storage_2->operator[](i) = ref;
    cout<< "use count after: "<< storage_1->operator[](i).use_count()<<endl;
  }


  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

> output
>
> use count before : 1
>
> use count after: 1
>
> use count before : 1
>
> use count after: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do `storage_2d_t storage_2 = storage_1;` obviously, assigning the elements *directly back onto themselves* should not increase use counts.

I the second loop you print the use count during the time where you hold the temporary copy (`ref`). Making it explicit, you can see that indeed - as expected - the "after" count is not actually higher:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim2; ++i) {
    cout << "use count before : " << (*storage_1)[i].use_count() << endl;
    {
        storage_1d_t ref = (*storage_1)[i];
        (*storage_2)[i] = ref;
        cout << "use count during: " << (*storage_1)[i].use_count() << endl;
    }
    cout << "use count after: " << (*storage_1)[i].use_count() << endl;
}
```

Now prints

```
use count before : 1
use count during: 2
use count after: 1
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f48c212ea82576f)**

---

**Brainwave** Did you mean to deep-clone `storage_1` into `storage_2`? It appears you have been confused by the fact that your outer storage_2d_t is *also* a shared pointer and hence you refer to the same vector by reference.

```
storage_2d_t storage_2 = boost::make_shared<content_2d_t>(*storage_1);
// or
storage_2d_t storage_2 = boost::make_shared<content_2d_t>(storage_1->begin(), storage_1->end());
```

Comment: I don't want to deep clone the shared pointers. I just one to increase the use_count when the shallow copy constructor of the shared_pointer is called. So you brought my attention that the trick just increased the use_count for the lifetime of temporary copy. So why am I not able to increase it when I am assigning (*storage_2)[i] = (*storage_1)[i]. This is assigning shared pointers and must call the copy constructor of the shared pointers which will increase the use count during the lifetime of (*storage_2)[i] ...

Comment: @mustafabar Did you completely miss the point of my first sentence? You're **not** copying. You're assigning the elements to **itself**. `storage_1` and `storage_2` point to ***the same container***.

Comment: I didn't miss your point. A smart pointer copy constructor is essentially a copy of the addresses, not a deep copy of the pointed-to data. This should increase the reference count to this piece of memory without allocation of new memory.

Comment: @mustafabar Reading comprehension. Let me spell it out some more: `storage_1.get() == storage_2.get()` is true. Hence, `(*storage_1)[i].get() == (*storage_2)[i].get()` is true. Hence `(*storage_2)[i] = (*storage_1)[i];` doesn't **do anything**

Comment: of course its true, because with .get(), you are comparing the raw addresses of the pointers which are the same. The share_ptr is a wrapper over this. Anyhow, look at my code again, and cout<<storage_1.use_count() before and after the line ((storage_2d_t storage_2 = storage_1;)), which "doesn't do anything and does not increase use count" according to you

Comment: @mustafabar I've explained ***that*** in the second sentence of my answer with a demonstration to follow. If you're unwilling to read my answer and try to understand it, I'm done here. You don't need to tell me I'm not understanding it. After all, it was **you** who came to SO with the question?

Comment: Final summary: you can expect the use_count to go up when you copy a shared_ptr to ***another shared_ptr***. Not when you "copy" it to itself. Demonstration: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82cc9b8b72810392)**